# SQL Select Master Records and Display Number of Detail Records for Each

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Master and Detail table, the Detail linking to the Master record on a FK reference.

I need to display all the data from the Master table, and the corresponding number of details for each record, i.e.

```
MASTER TABLE
ID Name  Age
1  John  15
2  Jane  14 
3  Joe   15

DETAIL
MasterID Subjects
1        Trigonometry
1        Chemistry
1        Physics
1        History
2        Trigonometry
2        Physics
```

Thus, when I ran the SQL statement, I would have the following result:

```
ID Name Age #Subjects
1  John 15  4  
2  Jane 14  2
3  Joe  15  0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may be useful

```
SELECT mt.ID, mt.NAME, mt.AGE, COUNT(d.MasterID) as [#Subjects]
FROM MasterTable mt
LEFT OUTER JOIN Detail d on mt.ID = d.ID
GROUP BY mt.ID, mt.NAME, mt.AGE
ORDER BY mt.ID
```

Comment: You'll need to coalesce d.MasterID to zero before counting it, or it'll return NULL for master records with no children (like Joe).

Comment: Great. The keyword missing from the SQL I wrote was the word *OUTER*.

Comment: @djacobson - could you explain further? Right now, it is returning 0 if no detail record was found, as posted by @bobs.

Comment: Don't need the coalesce when using COUNT(column).  You would need it for a SUM, as an example.  If you use coalesce in this case, it would return 1 instead of 0.

Comment: You're right. I was confused, because `COUNT(column)` skips NULLs, but it does indeed return 0 when it encounters them, not NULL. Good call!

Answer (score 8):

```
select id, 
       name, 
       age, 
       ( select count(*) 
           from detail 
          where master.id = detail.id )  as record_count
  from master
```

syntax adjusted depending on what db you are using

Comment: I agree about sub-queries in general. But in this case, I don't. I just tried it on some large real tables. Both generated exactly the same query plan. To me, the sub-query version is more explicitly descriptive of what I am trying to do.

Comment: SQL Server syntax allows this construct and it is easy to understand.